# Failure to push application to Bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

I' trying to push a Node.js application to Bluemix, using cf push, but get the following error.  I recently upgraded to MacOS Sierra and have a feeling it might be the reason.

Anyone else has the same problem and was able to resolve the issue?

```
failed MSpanList_Insert 0x202d520 0x43fe75013ff0 0x0
fatal error: MSpanList_Insert

runtime stack:
runtime.MSpanList_Insert(0xbb4558, 0x202d520)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/mheap.c:692 +0x8f
runtime.MHeap_FreeStack(0xbb4480, 0x202d520)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/mheap.c:518 +0x9f

goroutine 1 [select]:
net/http.(*Transport).getConn(0xc20843a1b0, 0xc2082125b0, 0x0, 0xc2081f32c0, 0x5, 0xc2084c3260, 0x16, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/transport.go:525 +0x608
net/http.(*Transport).RoundTrip(0xc20843a1b0, 0xc2082125b0, 0xc208ca4d20, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/transport.go:228 +0x4d4
net/http.send(0xc2082125b0, 0x2011f58, 0xc20843a1b0, 0x6b, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/client.go:219 +0x4fc
net/http.(*Client).send(0xc20825e3f0, 0xc2082125b0, 0x6b, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/client.go:142 +0x15b
net/http.(*Client).doFollowingRedirects(0xc20825e3f0, 0xc2082125b0, 0x8ec4f0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/client.go:367 +0xb25
net/http.(*Client).Do(0xc20825e3f0, 0xc2082125b0, 0xc20825e3f0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/client.go:177 +0x192
github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/cf/net.Gateway.doRequest(0x201b8b8, 0xc20824a2d0, 0x8ebce0, 0x1, 0x12a05f200, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x201b658, 0xc2082628d0, ...)
    /Users/cffadmin/go-agent/pipelines/Mac-OSX-Unit-Tests/src/github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/tmp/cli_gopath/src/github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/cf/net/gateway.go:425 +0x117
github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/cf/net.Gateway.doRequestAndHandlerError(0x201b8b8, 0xc20824a2d0, 0x8ebce0, 0x1, 0x12a05f200, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x201b658, 0xc2082628d0, ...)
    /Users/cffadmin/go-agent/pipelines/Mac-OSX-Unit-Tests/src/github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/tmp/cli_gopath/src/github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/cf/net/gateway.go:399 +0x69
github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/cf/net.Gateway.doRequestHandlingAuth(0x201b8b8, 0xc20824a2d0, 0x8ebce0, 0x1, 0x12a05f200, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x201b658, 0xc2082628d0, ...)
    /Users/cffadmin/go-agent/pipelines/Mac-OSX-Unit-Tests/src/github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/tmp/cli_gopath/src/github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/cf/net/gateway.go:370 +0x197
github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/cf/net.Gateway.performRequestForResponseBytes(0x201b8b8, 0xc20824a2d0, 0x8ebce0, 0x1, 0x12a05f200, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x201b658, 0xc2082628d0, ...)
    /Users/cffadmin/go-agent/pipelines/Mac-OSX-Unit-Tests/src/github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/tmp/cli_gopath/src/github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/cf/net/gateway.go:249 +0xf3
github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/cf/net.Gateway.PerformPollingRequestForJSONResponse(0x201b8b8, 0xc20824a2d0, 0x8ebce0, 0x1, 0x12a05f200, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x201b658, 0xc2082628d0, ...)
    /Users/cffadmin/go-agent/pipelines/Mac-OSX-Unit-Tests/src/github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/tmp/cli_gopath/src/github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/cf/net/gateway.go:292 +0x309
github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/cf/net.Gateway.createUpdateOrDeleteResource(0x201b8b8, 0xc20824a2d0, 0x8ebce0, 0x1, 0x12a05f200, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x201b658, 0xc2082628d0, ...)
    /Users/cffadmin/go-agent/pipelines/Mac-OSX-Unit-Tests/src/github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/tmp/cli_gopath/src/github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/cf/net/gateway.go:187 +0x2f0
github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/cf/net.Gateway.UpdateResource(0x201b8b8, 0xc20824a2d0, 0x8ebce0, 0x1, 0x12a05f200, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x201b658, 0xc2082628d0, ...)
    /Users/cffadmin/go-agent/pipelines/Mac-OSX-Unit-Tests/src/github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/tmp/cli_gopath/src/github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/cf/net/gateway.go:126 +0x104
github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/cf/api/applications.CloudControllerApplicationRepository.Update(0x201b658, 0xc2082628d0, 0x201b8b8, 0xc20824a2d0, 0x8ebce0, 0x1, 0x12a05f200, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, ...)
    /Users/cffadmin/go-agent/pipelines/Mac-OSX-Unit-Tests/src/github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/tmp/cli_gopath/src/github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/cf/api/applications/applications.go:101 +0x4e9
github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/cf/api/applications.(*CloudControllerApplicationRepository).Update(0xc20824a3f0, 0xc208262780, 0x24, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc20818c2c0, 0xc2080f6800, 0xc208033598, 0x0, 0x0, ...)
    <autogenerated>:5 +0x126
github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/cf/commands/application.(*Push).updateApp(0xc20816ae00, 0xc208262780, 0x24, 0xc2084b3220, 0xf, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, ...)
    /Users/cffadmin/go-agent/pipelines/Mac-OSX-Unit-Tests/src/github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/tmp/cli_gopath/src/github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/cf/commands/application/push.go:377 +0x7ae
github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/cf/commands/application.(*Push).createOrUpdateApp(0xc20816ae00, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc20818c2c0, 0xc2080f6800, 0xc208033598, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc2080f6da0, 0xc20818c3f8, ...)
    /Users/cffadmin/go-agent/pipelines/Mac-OSX-Unit-Tests/src/github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/tmp/cli_gopath/src/github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/cf/commands/application/push.go:328 +0x201
github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/cf/commands/application.(*Push).Execute(0xc20816ae00, 0x201cf60, 0xc208226f00)
    /Users/cffadmin/go-agent/pipelines/Mac-OSX-Unit-Tests/src/github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/tmp/cli_gopath/src/github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/cf/commands/application/push.go:144 +0x32b
main.main()
    /Users/cffadmin/go-agent/pipelines/Mac-OSX-Unit-Tests/src/github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/main/main.go:79 +0xf02

goroutine 6 [syscall]:
os/signal.loop()
    /usr/local/go/src/os/signal/signal_unix.go:21 +0x1f
created by os/signal.init·1
    /usr/local/go/src/os/signal/signal_unix.go:27 +0x35

goroutine 366 [runnable]:
net/http.(*Transport).dialConn(0xc20843a1b0, 0x0, 0xc2081f32c0, 0x5, 0xc2084c3260, 0x16, 0xc208218180, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/transport.go:643 +0x8d3
net/http.func·019()
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/transport.go:520 +0x42
created by net/http.(*Transport).getConn
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/transport.go:522 +0x335

goroutine 359 [IO wait]:
net.(*pollDesc).Wait(0xc2081fd3a0, 0x72, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/fd_poll_runtime.go:84 +0x47
net.(*pollDesc).WaitRead(0xc2081fd3a0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/fd_poll_runtime.go:89 +0x43
net.(*netFD).Read(0xc2081fd340, 0xc2081eb000, 0x400, 0x400, 0x0, 0x2011d88, 0xc2084c4f88)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/fd_unix.go:242 +0x40f
net.(*conn).Read(0xc208033698, 0xc2081eb000, 0x400, 0x400, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/net.go:121 +0xdc
crypto/tls.(*block).readFromUntil(0xc20825ee40, 0x201eff0, 0xc208033698, 0x5, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/crypto/tls/conn.go:454 +0xe6
crypto/tls.(*Conn).readRecord(0xc208078580, 0x17, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/crypto/tls/conn.go:539 +0x2da
crypto/tls.(*Conn).Read(0xc208078580, 0xc208107000, 0x1000, 0x1000, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/crypto/tls/conn.go:904 +0x166
net/http.noteEOFReader.Read(0x2034e50, 0xc208078580, 0xc208051238, 0xc208107000, 0x1000, 0x1000, 0x5f2380, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/transport.go:1270 +0x6e
net/http.(*noteEOFReader).Read(0xc208a745a0, 0xc208107000, 0x1000, 0x1000, 0xc208012000, 0x0, 0x0)
    <autogenerated>:125 +0xd4
bufio.(*Reader).fill(0xc2081f2f00)
    /usr/local/go/src/bufio/bufio.go:97 +0x1ce
bufio.(*Reader).Peek(0xc2081f2f00, 0x1, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/bufio/bufio.go:132 +0xf0
net/http.(*persistConn).readLoop(0xc2080511e0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/transport.go:842 +0xa4
created by net/http.(*Transport).dialConn
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/transport.go:660 +0xc9f

goroutine 369 [syscall, locked to thread]:
runtime.goexit()
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:2232 +0x1

goroutine 360 [select]:
net/http.(*persistConn).writeLoop(0xc2080511e0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/transport.go:945 +0x41d
created by net/http.(*Transport).dialConn
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/transport.go:661 +0xcbc

goroutine 364 [IO wait]:
net.(*pollDesc).Wait(0xc208d17170, 0x72, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/fd_poll_runtime.go:84 +0x47
net.(*pollDesc).WaitRead(0xc208d17170, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/fd_poll_runtime.go:89 +0x43
net.(*netFD).Read(0xc208d17110, 0xc208d29000, 0x1000, 0x1000, 0x0, 0x2011d88, 0xc2084c48f0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/fd_unix.go:242 +0x40f
net.(*conn).Read(0xc2080338e0, 0xc208d29000, 0x1000, 0x1000, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/net.go:121 +0xdc
crypto/tls.(*block).readFromUntil(0xc208455b90, 0x201eff0, 0xc2080338e0, 0x5, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/crypto/tls/conn.go:454 +0xe6
crypto/tls.(*Conn).readRecord(0xc208079080, 0x17, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/crypto/tls/conn.go:539 +0x2da
crypto/tls.(*Conn).Read(0xc208079080, 0xc208d61000, 0x1000, 0x1000, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/crypto/tls/conn.go:904 +0x166
net/http.noteEOFReader.Read(0x2034e50, 0xc208079080, 0xc208d543c8, 0xc208d61000, 0x1000, 0x1000, 0x5f2380, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/transport.go:1270 +0x6e
net/http.(*noteEOFReader).Read(0xc208a52d00, 0xc208d61000, 0x1000, 0x1000, 0xc208012000, 0x0, 0x0)
    <autogenerated>:125 +0xd4
bufio.(*Reader).fill(0xc2081f2420)
    /usr/local/go/src/bufio/bufio.go:97 +0x1ce
bufio.(*Reader).Peek(0xc2081f2420, 0x1, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/bufio/bufio.go:132 +0xf0
net/http.(*persistConn).readLoop(0xc208d54370)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/transport.go:842 +0xa4
created by net/http.(*Transport).dialConn
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/transport.go:660 +0xc9f

goroutine 365 [select]:
net/http.(*persistConn).writeLoop(0xc208d54370)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/transport.go:945 +0x41d
created by net/http.(*Transport).dialConn
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/transport.go:661 +0xcbc
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please make sure you update to latest CLI release

https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/releases/tag/v6.22.1

as it has fix for Mac OS Sierra. From the change log:

> Mac OS Sierra
>
> The cf CLI is now built with Golang 1.7.1, adding support for Mac OS
>   Sierra as well as showing a reduction in filesize of binaries and
>   installers for all platforms.

This issue was reported in the following Github issue:
https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/issues/944